# MultiDimensional Array in Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multidimensional-array

EveryBody..

i want to create one 8*8 dimensional array in objective c..

```
(
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
)
```

like that..
And also use as one of the object can moved in it..
Like want to move

```
MOVE_ARRAY = array([0, 0], [0, 2])
```

And also check the array's any position like 5*6 or 4*3 any..
So, Can any one help me about how to initialize , and how to use in code ?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know to create a multidimensional(2D) array in any other programming language? Also a 64D would redefine physics. I am assuming you need a 2D array.

Comment: Objective C is backward compatible with C/C++. You can create a simple C array and use it... if you cannot create that, you've a lot of ground to cover before you jump into iPhone development..

Comment: @WTP i didn't told that array is 64D.. i just show you the position of the objects in.

Comment: @Praveen S.. yes i need 2D array and i displaying the positions of the  objects..

Comment: @lukya.. So i am not able to do iPhone development ?

Comment: @WTP that is my objects position to displaying in one array.. this is as like [a,1],[a,2],...,[d,1],..,[g,8], .... [h,8] that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Objective-C:

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        [subArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]; 
    }
    [array addObject:subArray];
    [subArray release];
}
```

(`array` is an instance variable, that has to be added to your header file and released in you `dealloc` method)

To retrieve a value at a certain position you could write a method like this:

```
- (int)valueAtRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)col {
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    return [[subArray objectAtIndex:col] intValue];
}
```

=== UPDATE ===

To remove an object you could do this:

```
- (void)removeObjectAtRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)col {
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    [subArray removeObjectAtIndex:col];
}
```

You have to be careful though, because removing objects will change the structure of the array (e.g. the row where you removed an object will have only 7 items after the removal. So you might want to think about leaving the structure intact and set the values that you want to delete to a value that you normally don't use:

```
- (void)removeObjectAtRow:(int)row andColumn:(int)col {
    NSMutableArray *subArray = [array objectAtIndex:row];
    [subArray replaceObjectAtIndex:col withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-999]];
}
```

Comment: And If i want to remove the any position , So how i could ?

Comment: With such implementation it's not possible just to write array[i][j]. But question was in that. So -1...

Comment: Hey joerm... I m very thankful to you.. And need one more help. One more query, i m using this array and in running code i need to change index with another index.. How it ?

Comment: Hi Jagdish. I'm afraid I do not fully understand what you try to achieve. Do you want to swap two values? Like for example swap the value in row 1, column 2 with the value at row2 and column 1?

Answer (score 2):

In C:

```
int **array = (int**)calloc(8, sizeof(int*));
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) array[i] = (int*)calloc(8, sizeof(int));
// use your array
// cleaning:
for (int i=0; i<8; i++) free(array[i]);
free(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a constant 2d array containing integers,simply do something like:

```
NSArray *array;
array = @[@[@1, @7, @4, @11],@[@2, @6, @9]];
```

This creates an array

```
1 7 4 11
2 6 9
```