# remove object from a nested array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an NSMutableArray that contains an array inside it. the structure is like this.

pseudocode:

```
 myArray[0][1]
```

my question is how am I going to remove that object from my array? I know I can use [array removeObjectAtIndex:int] which only takes one index(or outer index for this case), but how can I remove an inner array object?

Comment: look at this answer.  
it may help you  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227360/multidimensional-array-in-objective-c

Comment: You can also check NSMutableArray class reference for other clues http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] removeObjectAtIndex:int];
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to do get the inner array and then remove from that inner array:

```
[[outer objectAtIndex:i] removeObjectAtIndex:j];
```

where i is the index to the inner array and j is the index within that inner array of the object to remove.